# Save images to photo library ONLY if they are taken by camera and not if chosen from photo library

Tags: ios, save, photos

I have a photo picker in my app that asks the user if they want to take a picture or choose one from the photo library. Upon completion of their choice I set an image view to their chosen image and I want to save the image they just set only if it was taken from the camera and not if it was just an edited version of a photo they already have. The last method listed here is the one in which I wish to save the photo.

```
- (IBAction)startPicker:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIActionSheet *picChoice = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", @"Photo Library", nil];
        [picChoice showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
    } else {
        UIActionSheet *picChoice = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Photo Library", nil];
        [picChoice showFromRect:[(UIButton *)sender frame] inView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
}


- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Camera"]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    } else if ([[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Photo Library"]) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    } else {
        return;
    } 
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *editedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:editedImage.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)editedImage.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error )
 {
     NSLog(@"IMAGE SAVED TO PHOTO ALBUM");
     [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset )
      {
          NSLog(@"we have our ALAsset!");
      }
             failureBlock:^(NSError *error )
      {
          NSLog(@"Error loading asset");
      }];
 }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent saving picture from camera roll again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876723/how-to-prevent-saving-picture-from-camera-roll-again)

Comment: FYI - I would not normally post an answer to a question I also flag as a duplicate but that duplicate question is such a mess that the answer isn't too obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check the `sourceType`:

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    // save to library
}
```

Do this in your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.